# How can you alter the name of attributes in a shortcode?

Tags: shortcode

I'm trying to write a shortcode for a button, here's how it looks

```
/**
 * Button Shortcodes
 */
function btn_shortcode( $atts, $content = null ) {
    $a = shortcode_atts( array(
        'class' => 'btn',
        'href' => '#',
    ), $atts );

    return '<a class="' . esc_attr($a['class']) . '"' . ' ' . 'href="' . esc_attr($a['href']) . '">' . $content . '</a>';
}
add_shortcode( 'button', 'btn_shortcode' );
```

It works like this `[button class="btn btn-primary" href="domain.com"]Learn More[/button]` but I'd like to change it to make it a bit easier for someone to come in and modify these things, I'd like the shortcode to look like this `[button class="btn btn-primary" link="domain.com"]Learn More[/button]`, so I changed `href` to `link`.

Comment: Whats your question? You said "so I changed href to link." is that not the answer you were looking for?

Comment: I said that to state the difference. If I change it to "link" the button no longer has a `href`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function jk_WPSCEX_add_message( $atts )
{
   $output = '<a href="' . $atts['link'] . '">' . $atts['text'] . '</a>';
   return $output;
}
```

using the above function  shortcode is generated in the form of `[jk link="http://jaskokoyn.com" text="Like me on Facebook"]`

OR
For Enclosed type of shortcode:

```
function jk_WPSCEX_add_message( $atts, $content = null )
{
   $output = '<a href="' . $atts['link'] . '">' . $content . '</a>';
   return $output; 
}
```

shortcode to be used is `[jk link="http://jaskokoyn.com"]Like us on Facebook[/jk]`